# Why this server work with python requests but not in node.js? (ECCONRESET)

Tags: c++, node.js, http, esp8266

I have an ESP8266 microcontroller running this code. This little server will receive request, take parameters and do things.

If I use python's requests to make the request it works fine:

```
import requests
r = requests.get('http://192.168.1.202/15/1')
```

No errors are throwed, status_code == 200, so it's all ok.

I wanted to write the same code in node, but

```
const http = require('http');
const url = 'http://192.168.1.202/15/1';
http
  .get(url, (res) => {
    let data = [];
    res
      .on('data', (d) => {
        console.log('received data');
        data.push(d);
      })
      .on('error', (e) => {
        console.log('error', e);
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('call ended');
        console.log('data', data);
      });
  });
```

raises

> Error: socket hang up [...] CODE: 'ECONNRESET'

So I want to understand why it is raised. This is the code in server side in `loop`:

```
if (checkConnection()) {
    // Connected to WiFi

    WiFiClient client = server.available();               // Listen for incoming clients
    if (client) {                                         // If a new client connects,
      bool reading = false;
      bool read = false;
      char buffer_http[HTTP_BUFFER_LENGTH + 1];           // make a buffer to hold incoming data from the client

      int buffer_index = 0;                               // length of message
      long unsigned time_connected = millis();
      delay(2);
      while (client.connected()) {                        // loop while the client's connected

        if ((millis() - time_connected) > HTTP_TIMEOUT) { // max time reached HTTP_TIMEOUT = 4000 ms
          client.stop();
        }

        if (client.available()) {                           // if there's bytes to read from the client,
          char c = client.read();                           // read a byte

          // HANDLE c here

        } else {
          client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
          delay(5);
          client.stop();
          delay(10);
          Serial.println(buffer_http);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: if `client.available()` returns false you send a response and close the connection, what if the client hasn't finished sending its request? Your response is also not a complete http response so the client will fail. I imagine if you tried to read the request body in your python code you'd also get an error

Comment: Just solved, thanks.